# SSH into my own machine on my local network (no access to peripherals and remote access is not turned on)

Tags: networking, ssh, windows, windows-10, kubuntu-netbook

I'm wondering if I can access my Windows 10 machine from another machine, both on the same network. I know the IP and my user/the pass for it but otherwise do not have access to the computer. I want to do this because the PC receives power but isn't powering any of its peripherals at the moment and I'm not sure what else I could do. Thanks

- I tried plugging in multiple different sets of peripherals to no avail
- I also tried to plug in an autorun enabled USB so it'd type my password in and login automatically but that failed too

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? This looks like a Windows and or hardware problem. How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I got two running Kubuntu atm and the pc i'm trying to access is windows 10

Comment: I'm trying to SSH into the windows machine- it's a windows issue, but I'm asking how to get into my pc from ubuntu

Comment: Do you have ssh server installed in Windows?

Comment: no, i do not- all i have to go by are i know the login/password, it's on my home network, i know the IP and machine name, ik it's running windows 10

- i can turn on and off the machine but other than that none of the peripherals i've connected are working, not even the monitor

Comment: If an ssh server is not running in Windows, then trying to connect using ssh is a dead end. Consult a Windows support venue for other alternative connection methods (if any).

Comment: According to Microsoft, [the openSSH server is not installed by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent ssh client is included with all releases and flavors of Ubuntu (except Ubuntu Server). No separate application is needed.

Simply open a terminal.

`ssh <windows_username>@<windows_ip_address>`

See `man ssh` for usage examples and options.